# GIMP - How to make a GIF with transparent background

Tags: gimp, transparency, background, gif

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make a GIF in GIMP to use as a logo in After Effects, however, it's not going well.

What I expected was just the gif with the transparent background I made using the fuzzy select, shown here:

[image]

However, I receive this.

[image]

And when I import to After Effects, the white background completely screws me over.

Comment: Should have worked in Gimp. Hard to diagnose because Imgur has changed your GIF into a video. Can you post the XCF somewhere (dropbox or else)? If you change your frames to `(replace)` does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure none of your frames have any white background. Then when you export as GIF, use the settings shown in the screenshot below.

Imgur has changed your GIF by the way, and seems to have messed it up by adding a white background and other frames. I had to erase them and delete out the messed up backgrounds to get it to work properly. Probably something to do with changing the GIF to a GIFV - which is actually a video file, not a GIF

Screenshot of GIF export settings[image: Screenshot of GIF export settings]

You can download the fixed GIF here: http://www.filedropper.com/test_298