# Removing white dots from gif

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I was trying to remove background from this gif in photoshop.

[image]

When I was done I saved it for web but my problem is that when playing the gif after saving, loads of white dots appear out of nowhere. Can I do something about that?

Comment: You could alternatively try this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/106302/2332

Comment: That gif is very funny.

Comment: Thanks Joonas, i tried it. Those white dots dissapered, but it also deletes the white bunny -__

Comment: Yea, I don't think there's a way out of that one, given all the gaps in those frames before the fire. — Getting back to the original question. Is this gif the one with the issue after export? I'm on mobile right now so I have no idea. Are you sure the dots appears after export and it's not just something you missed?  I might be able to figure this out if I was on desktop, but figured I'd ask anyways.

Comment: I think I would've used After Effects. First key out the background much like how that online tool does it and then "refill" the white bunny background. That seems like the easiest method to me.

Comment: https://youtu.be/dLT0powiOLw thats the video of the problem, and Yeah i am pretty sure since the background is pure white and i was even double checking by trying to delete those areas with square thingy aswell

Comment: So I now looked at the gif on a desktop and the gif you posted here is I guess the original with the white background, so I'm still left wondering what kinda dots were talking about. My best guess at the moment would be that you still got some translucent pixels in the document and they get 100% opacity when you export it to gif. Can't think of anything else that would produce dots of any kind on export.

Comment: Well I posted you a video where you can see the gif with the problem. The way i did it was to create 104 png files and than put them together with different software xD that was something gotta tell you :D , but if there was a way to do in photoshop i would be curious how for the future

Comment: Well, the thing is, the document zoom level in the video is not big enough to see any anomalies in the document (the transparency grid doesn't help either) and you did say the dots appeared after the export, so there shouldn't be anything in it anyways. The exported gif with the issue might help identify the issue, but it also might not. If you could dropbox link to the .psd file I could check that out.

Comment: Here you go, https://www.dropbox.com/s/21alfj7njjocagu/This%20was%20something.psd?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is what I suspected in the comments. There are translucent pixels all around in various frames. Gif file format doesn't support that. Pixels are either fully opaque or fully transparent, so when you export that, it makes all of those seemingly nonexistent translucent pixels visible.

I checked this before the export by: giving the document a background, adding a Levels adjustment layer with blend mode `difference` to bring out any translucent pixel:

[image]

Luckily in this situation, you can get rid of the dots by adjusting `Transparency Dithering` when exporting.

**In the "Safe for web" window, you need the following:**

- `Transparency` checkbox checked
- Below that in the dropdown list: `Diffusion transparency` (probably any of the three would work in this case)
- To the right from the previous dropdown list: `Amount` set to `0`

**Another major thing** I noticed about in the psd file. Make sure to select all frames in the `Timeline` panel and right click the little bouncy ball icon on the bottom left of one of the frames and set frame disposal method as `dispose`. This will prevent frame overlapping.

With those changes the exported gif will be more like this one... Without the black background of course...

[image]

In your quest to remove the background, I guess, you left a bunch of white pixels surrounding the dark grey edge. You could try to get rid of it with `Layer > Matting > Defringe...`, but I'm not sure if it's worth it, because you'd have to do it to every layer and the end result might not be that much better.

Comment: Thank you Joonas very much for all your help. I really do appreciate it. That thing worked for me perfectly. Also I tried to edit every single layer with the defrindge thing by 1 pixel. It got way better as you can see here :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s95pbs46t0jd7ls/This-was-something-defringed.gif?dl=0

but there is still little bit of white pixels left. Is there something left I can do about it to make it even smoother or is that it? Thanks once again

Comment: @Bleez, I don't think there is much more you can do aside from like manual frame by frame masking or recoloring the white pixels at the edge. I don't really do animation in PS, so it could just be my limited thinking, but I feel like it would be even easier to just take the original and make better selections frame by frame. Would probably take less effort to track down the original creator of that and force them to export it without a background (or with a specific matte color).